# for which test cases did the code go wrong?

Tags: c, sorting, structure

the following program is for the question from the link
https://www.codechef.com/problems/ENTEXAM

but when submitted the software shows wrong answer. i tested for several cases and got the right answer. did i miss any corner cases?

```
 #include<stdio.h>

struct student
{
    long long int E[4],tot;
}stud[10001];

int main()
{
    long long int T,i;
    scanf("%d",&T);
    for(i=0;i<T;i++)
    {   
        long long int N,K,E,M,j;
        scanf("%lld%lld%lld%lld",&N,&K,&E,&M);
        for(j=0;j<N-1;j++)
        {   long long int k;
            stud[j].tot=0;
            for(k=0;k<E;k++)
            {
                scanf("%lld",&stud[j].E[k]);
                stud[j].tot=stud[j].tot+stud[j].E[k];
            }
        }
        sortmark(N);
        long long int k;
        stud[N-1].tot=0;
        for(k=0;k<E-1;k++)
        {
            scanf("%lld",&stud[N-1].E[k]);
            stud[N-1].tot=stud[N-1].tot+stud[N-1].E[k];
        }
        long long int diff;
        diff=stud[K-1].tot-stud[N-1].tot+1;
        if(diff<0) diff=0;
        if(diff<=M&&diff>0)
        printf("%lld\n",diff);
        else printf("impossible\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

int sortmark(int);
int sortmark(int N)
{
    long long int i,j,temp;
    for(i=0;i<N-1;i++)
    {
        temp=stud[i].tot;
        for(j=i;j>0&&stud[j-1].tot<stud[j].tot;j--)
        {
            stud[j].tot=stud[j-1].tot;
            stud[j-1].tot=temp;
        }
        stud[j].tot=temp;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For heaven's sake if you can't read the question properly you won't get the right answer. It says *output `"Impossible"`*, but you have output `"impossible"`.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems:

1. You call the `sortmark` function before you declare it. Move the prototype to before the call (i.e. before the `main` function).
2. The prototype of the `sortmark` function doesn't match how you call it. You say it takes an `int` argument, but passes a `long long int` argument to the function. The `int` type is typically 32 bits, even on 64 bit systems, while `long long int` is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits. That means you can lose half the bits when calling the function, leading to very weird values being passed to the function.

The first problem should have given you a compiler warning. And when you fixed that the second problem would have given you another compiler warning. Compiler warnings are very important to fix, as they often indicate cases of just like yours with mixed types. And if the first problem doesn't give you a warning, then you need to up the warning level of your compiler.